# c# method type inference troubles

Tags: c#, .net, types, inference

I'm having trouble getting c# method type inference to work for me, I in essence have the following sample, but this produces the error.

CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Test.Connect(T1)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
public void Main()
{
    new Test<int>().Connect(new Test2()); // CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Test<int>.Connect<T1, T2>(T1)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
}

public class Test2 : ITest<Test<int>, Delegate>
{

}

public class Test<T>
{
    public void Connect<T1, T2>(T1 entity)
        where T1 : ITest<Test<int>, T2>
        where T2 : Delegate
    {
    }
}

public interface ITest<T1, T2>
    where T1 : Test<int>
    where T2 : Delegate
{
}
```

Should the compiler be able to infer the parameters T1 and T2 from the class given? I would guess it should, am I missing something?

Comment: The new constraint would only matter when I would actually try to use the new key word in the method, new constraint only means the type specified must have a default constructor, but thanks for the comment

Comment: new Test<int>().Connect<Test2, Delegate>(new Test2());

Comment: I'm trying to let the compiler figure out the Connect<Test2, Delegate> part, like when using the method definition like **void Connect<T>(T value) 
 where T : class
{
 
}** with such a definition you can use the method call like this **Connect(new Test())** omitting the type definition because the compiler can figure it out

Comment: But the Connect signature has fewer types of parameters than the generic type param (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the compiler be able to infer the parameters T1 and T2 from the class given?

No.

> I would guess it should, am I missing something?

Your guess is plausible, and common, but incorrect.

Type parameters are never inferred from constraints, only from arguments. You have enough information to deduce the type of T1, but the compiler does not deduce from the constraint what T2 must be.

The compiler could in theory make deductions from constraints, but we decided to infer only from arguments. The type inference algorithm is complex and hard to explain, and hard to implement; adding constraint inferences would make it more complex and harder to explain and harder to implement.

Comment: So there is no way the compiler will deduce T2 for me except literally passing the type?

Comment: @Ronald: That's correct. If a type parameter appears in no formal parameter types, type inference cannot succeed.

Comment: Thank you for the insights, hoped the make a base class easier to use, but a redesign of the implementation is the way to go then I figure.

Comment: @Ronald: Usually in these cases the sensible thing to do is `public void Connect<T>(ITest<Test<int>, T> entity)` However, a constraint of `Delegate` is suspicious. Can you say what you're trying to do? This sounds like an "XY" problem; you've got a wrong idea about how to solve the real problem, and are asking about the wrong idea. Ask a question about the real problem you have.

Comment: You are right, the delegate is just the first class that came to mind as a sample, I created a sample here where my problem is on line 122 https://gist.github.com/rvhelden/c56212da1a25af0abd671ad9e140ea0f here i would like to be able to just pass a inherited class of Entity without passing all the type parameters